# Oracle: Sending query result through email?

Tags: oracle

I'm extremely new to oracle and I've been tasked to send the result of a certain SELECT query through email and have it regularly scheduled as well. 
I've tried looking at other posts as well but I could not make sense of any of it.
Can someone show me how to do it in a simple way?

Comment: Take a minute and read this site: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/email-from-oracle-plsql

Comment: What format? CSV, PDF, XLSX?

Comment: Including what version of oracle you are on will help answer this.

Comment: ....and, if you have APEX installed

Comment: HTML format preferably and oracle 12c

Comment: You should consider doing this outside of the database as well

Answer (score 1):

## Workflow

This is the general workflow for how to email your report

- Generate a CLOB of the HTML Code

  - Use the HTF package to create the HTML code
- Email the CLOB

  - If you have APEX Installed

    - The `APEX_MAIL` package fits this requirement nicely
  - If not

    - try to create something using the `MAIL_UTL` package
- post a question asking why you aren't receiving emails

  - 20% of the time - this is due to missing ACL or firewall issues
  - 79% of the time - some system thinks you are a spammer
  - most likely, this question on DBA SA will be closed for being "too localized"

## Design Notes

You need to have three separate code blocks (`function` or `procedure`)

1. Code that generates the report in a specific format
2. Code that sends that `BLOB`/`CLOB` ( UTL_MAIL or APEX_MAIL )
3. Code that takes (1) and sends it to (2)

Further Details should be placed in a different question.

But, I'll show you how to generate the HTML anyways.

## Create HTML

```
create or replace
function generate_html_reports return clob
    authid current_user
as
    html_clob clob;

    cursor c is select rownum rn, banner from v$version;
BEGIN
  -- top of the HTML Page
   html_clob := HTF.HTMLOPEN -- generates <HTML>
   || HTF.HEADOPEN -- generates <HEAD>
   || HTF.TITLE('My Report') -- generates <TITLE>Hello</TITLE>
   || HTF.HEADCLOSE -- generates </HEAD>
   || chr(10)
   || HTF.BODYOPEN -- generates <BODY>
   || chr(10)
   || HTF.HEADER(1, 'Hello')  -- generates <H1>Hello</H1>
   || chr(10);

   -- Table prefix
    html_clob := html_clob
    || htf.tableopen
    || htf.tablerowopen
        || htf.tabledata( curr.rn ) || htf.tabledata( curr.banner )  -- generates all of the <td>data</td> code

    || htf.tablerowclose
    || chr(10);

    -- table data
    for curr in c
    loop
    html_clob := html_clob
    || htf.tablerowopen  -- generates <tr>
        || htf.tabledata('Row') || htf.tabledata( 'Banner' )  -- generates all of the <td>data</td> code
    || htf.tablerowclose
    || chr(10); -- generats </tr>
    end loop;

    -- close of table and HTML
    html_clob := html_clob
    || htf.tableclose
    || HTF.BODYCLOSE -- generates </BODY>
    || HTF.HTMLCLOSE -- generates </HTML>
    || chr(10);

    return html_clob;
END;
```